# How to check session without creating new one?

Tags: django, django-sessions

In part of my application i have some custom settings for visitors.
When user load page i try to check custom settings for request and if settings exist i do customization in page.

i do it in [Template Context Processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS)

```
def shared_values(request):

    show_help = request.session.get('show_help', True)
    return {
        'show_help': show_help,
    }
```

It's work perfect, but i have problem - each time, when i check session django create new entry in Session table if entry does not exist before.

How can i check session without creating new one?

Edit 1:

Then i disable checking for session key, i see what django does not create any Session entry for requests.

1. I login as admin in 1st browser (chrome) and delete all session (except one for mydself)
2. Edit context processor, so i don't access sessions in my project:

   show_help = True
3. Open page in different browser (firefox)
4. Switch to 1st browser and check if new session object is appear, but nothing has changed - only one session object exist.

Edit 2:

i use django 1.4.1

Answer (score 0):

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views):

> When `SessionMiddleware` is activated, each `HttpRequest` object – the
>   first argument to any Django view function – will have a `session`
>   attribute, which is a dictionary-like object.

So every time you make request - session will be created, if it does not exists already.
When `context_processor` is applied - session already exists. You should not worried about that.

Comment: Actually this is not true. Because then i disable checking for session key, i see what django does not create any Session entry.

Comment: I made an experiment. I removed all session entries in database and set a breakpoint at first line of first context_processor. I run debug , process stoped at breakpoint, I looked at database and... voila - there is new session entry. Maybe you should make more detailed description of the problem you have

Comment: What version of django do you have?

Comment: Django 1.4.1, on 1.4.2 i have the same result.